# Rust chromiumoxide library won't render iframe element

Tags: web-scraping, rust, headless-browser

I'm building a tauri app that does some web scraping. Tha problem I am facing is that, when the page contains an `iframe` that completly halts the page load.

I tried to visit a web page that contains an `iframe`, I expected the page to load properly, but the loading was halted instead.

The request in the `src` attribute is shown as "Pending" in the devtools, and stays like that until an eventual timeout.

I could somewhat fix that by using request interception to block the iframe's request, but I need the iframe to actually render, so that won't work.

Here is a minimal sample of the problem:

```rust
use chromiumoxide::{
    Browser, BrowserConfig, BrowserFetcher, BrowserFetcherOptions,
};
use futures::StreamExt;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let download_path = std::path::Path::new(".\\download");
    let _ = std::fs::create_dir_all(download_path);

    let fetcher_config = BrowserFetcherOptions::builder()
        .with_path(download_path)
        .build()?;

    let fetcher = BrowserFetcher::new(fetcher_config);

    let info = fetcher.fetch().await?;

    let config = BrowserConfig::builder()
        .chrome_executable(&info.executable_path)
        .user_data_dir("./data-dir")
        .with_head()
        .build()?;

    let (mut browser, mut handler) = Browser::launch(config).await.unwrap();

    let handle = tokio::spawn(async move {
        while let Some(h) = handler.next().await {
            if h.is_err() {
                break;
            }
        }
    });

    let page = browser.new_page("about:blank").await?;

    // Codepen may try to show you a captcha instead if you run this enough,
    // but since the captcha has an iframe, you will still see the problem happening
    page.goto("https://codepen.io/IanLintner/pen/DqGKQZ")
        .await?;

    // For you to be able to see the page loading
    tokio::time::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(30)).await;
    _ = browser.close().await;
    _ = browser.wait().await;

    _ = handle.await;

    Ok(())
}
```

I do also know that the `headless_chrome` crate doesn't have this issue, but it is way too slow for my purposes (selecting `td` elements from a small table takes about 45 seconds).

I really need to get it to work with `chromiumoxide` if at all possible